# PHP Output (function swap)

Tags: php

Can someone try to explain me why the output of this code is 2 , 12 ; 5 , 25 ?

```
<?php
function swap($x, $y){
  $x = $x + 1;
  $y = $y + 2;
  return $x * $y;
}

$a = 2;
$b = swap($a, $a);
print "$a, $b";
$b = swap(&$a, &$a);
print "$a, $b";
?>
```

Output:

```
2, 12
5, 25
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. what appears to be the problem?

Comment: Hi ! thanks for your comment ! Sorry for that , it's my first time here and i made a mistake . The question was why the output is 2,12  5, 25 .  Thanks for your answer !

Comment: there is no swap function in php. probably it is your own function

Comment: you are multiplying and returning result. no matter what you swap for x and y it will give the single result

Comment: 2 is what you have passed in first case and 12 is the output. similarly for the second case

Comment: caution!!! you are passing by reference in the second call.

Comment: First of all your function is called swap while it does not swap anything (so rename it to "calc" or something. Second... your second call gives **a reverence to $a** to the function. So $x and $y point to the same variable (being $a) and are effectively $a. So $a (and $x and $y) get +1 in the first line and +2 in the second. You get: $a = $a + 1 and $a = $a + 2 result in $a = 5 and 5*5 = 25. Because you gave a reference to $a your original variable is also changed (in 5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some explanation. The first call I think you have understood. I will explain the result of the second call in the code. Here you are passing the variable by reference.

when you call by reference the reference to the variable is passed so any change gets reflected in the original variable.

```
<?php
function swap($x, $y){
  //here your variable $a is 2
  $x = $x + 1;
  // added 1 to $a so $a is now 3 
  $y = $y + 2;
  //again added 2 to variable $a becomes 5
  return $x * $y; //returns 5*5=25
}

$a = 2;
$b = swap(&$a, &$a);
print "$a, $b";
?>
```

Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: Thanks !! For your explanation ! It's more clear now